# Vagrant execute long running command via ssh or via provisioning

Tags: linux, ssh, vagrant

I have a script that surely will take a long time to execute. 
I have a multi-machine installation.
On boot (preferably) I would like to have the script running on every one of the machines. 
However, I would like to do this asynchronously.

Alternatively I could execute vagrant ssh for each machine.

In the first case I add in the Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: 'bash /home/vagrant/shared_folder/script.sh  &'
...
```

Yet, although I can see a process running on each guest, it is not executed.

For the second case:

```
vagrant ssh client5 -c "/home/vagrant/shared_folder/script.sh  & sleep 1"
```

The sleep 1 is a "hack" suggested on another post. Yet, it runs only once and then exits.

The contents of the script are:

```
while [ true ];
do
        rand=`shuf -i 10-200 -n 1`
        curl "192.168.56.10/pages/"$rand"K.html"
        sleep 5
done
```

When I execute the script from inside the guest everything runs perfectly.

Comment: you are saying the provision command returns immediately or that the background task no longer runs once vagrant returns (the process gets killed somehow) where it shuold have been running in the background ?

Comment: in the provision case, when I do `vagrant ssh clientX`, I do a `sudo ps aux | grep script.sh` and I see the process id normally. However the script should do some curl and judging by the apache logs nothing gets requested. When inside the clientX if I run the same script the apache logs will tell me that apache is getting requests normally. Notice that I have `...script.sh  &` in the provision command in the Vagrant file.

Comment: I did notice that yes, thanks for the clarifications.  Have you looked at the stdout and stderr of the script ? try and redirect it to a file see if curl is complaining about something in these cases.